# Having trouble inserting values into a std::map with std::strings and std::vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, stdmap

I will post my code first then explain my issue:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<SEntity> Entity;
typedef std::vector<Entity> EntityVector;
typedef std::map<std::string, EntityVector> EntityVectorMap;

const void pushEntityVector(const std::string& key, const EntityVector& entity_vector)
{
    m_entity_vector_map[key] = entity_vector;
}
```

As you can probably see, I'm trying to insert an EntityVector into the EntityVectorMap. I'm hit with this issue when I do this however:

```
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h|335|error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = SE::SEntity; _Dp = std::default_delete<SE::SEntity>]'|
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're inserting a *copy* of `entity_vector`. That won't work as the elements are `unique_ptr`s, i.e. noncopyable, therefore the `vector` itself is noncopyable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m_entity_vector_map[key] = entity_vector` tries to copy an `EntityVector` thereby trying to copy 
an `Entity` which is essentially copying a `std::unique_ptr`. You cannot copy `std::unique_ptr` (it wouldn't be unique anymore).

You might want to move `entity_vector` into `m_entity_vector_map`, but then you cannot pass `entity_vector` as a const reference into `pushEntityVector`.